# API Returning Partial Text Recognition from Images: How to Retrieve Complete Text?

Tags: google-cloud-vision, text-recognition

I'm encountering an issue with an image processing API where it's only returning partial text recognition instead of the complete text present in the images. For instance, when the image contains a number like "24340", the API is returning only the first digit, "2".

I've ensured that the images provided for text recognition are clear and high-resolution, yet the API seems to truncate the text output. I'm looking for guidance on how to ensure the API retrieves the complete text from images.

Image -> https://imgur.com/a/FUkUn2f

Specifically, I'm seeking assistance in:

Understanding potential reasons behind the API's partial text recognition behavior.
Identifying parameters or configurations that might impact the completeness of text recognition.
Best practices or techniques to optimise the API usage for retrieving the entire text content present in the images.